# Ubuntu user not affected by sticky bit on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, flock, sticky-bit

I experience a strange behaviour in stick bit on /tmp directory and flock command. Tried with two cases:

Case 1: create file with Ubuntu user, root have no access to the created file.

```
ubuntu@:~$ touch -a /tmp/ubuntu_user_created.lck
ubuntu@:~$ flock -n /tmp/ubuntu_user_created.lck -c "echo 123"
123
ubuntu@:~$ sudo flock -n /tmp/ubuntu_user_created.lck -c "echo 123"
flock: cannot open lock file /tmp/ubuntu_user_created.lck: Permission denied
```

Case 2: create file with root user, root and Ubuntu user have access to the created file.

```
ubuntu@:~$ sudo touch -a /tmp/root_user_created.lck
ubuntu@:~$ flock -n /tmp/root_user_created.lck -c "echo 123"
123
ubuntu@:~$ sudo flock -n /tmp/root_user_created.lck -c "echo 123"
123
```

Permission in the two files:

```
ls -la /tmp/
total 52
drwxrwxrwt 12 root   root   4096 Oct  6 08:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root   root   4096 Oct  6 03:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Oct  6 07:56 root_user_created.lck
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Oct  6 07:54 ubuntu_user_created.lck
```

I don't understand why Ubuntu user can run the command `flock -n /tmp/root_user_created.lck` successfully, since the file r`oot_user_created.lck` is owned by root, does the flock command just want to open this file with read mode?

If the flock command only need a read access, so why run the command `flock -n /tmp/ubuntu_user_created.lck` command with root privileges return permission denied?